# Help on finding the domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{56-x}$ and $g(x)=x^2−x$ 
Then the domain of $f\circ g$ is equal to $[a,b]$ for $a =$  and $b =$

I keep getting $8$ for $a$ and $-7$ for $b$, but the site keeps saying that it's the wrong answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function $f∘g=\sqrt{56-(x^2-x)}$
so, it is only defined when $$56-x^2+x\ge0$$
Changing signs, we have $$x^2-x-56\le0$$
$$(x-8)(x+7)\le0$$
which if you do a test will find that  it is only true for $x\in[-7,8]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

With [interval notation](http://coolmath.com/algebra/07-solving-inequalities/03-interval-notation-01.htm), the lesser number is written first in the pair. So you'd want to choose $a$ and $b$ so that $a \leq b$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem**: Find the domain of the function $f\circ g$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{56-x}$ and $g(x)=x^2-x$.

---

First, let's determine $f\circ  g$: $$\begin{align}
f\circ g=\sqrt{56-g(x)}=\sqrt{56-(x^2-x)}=\sqrt{-x^2+x+56}
\end{align}.$$
We will use this property:

> **Property 1:** The square root of a number $x$ is defined in $\mathbb R$ only and only if $x\geqslant 0$.

As an example for this property: The $\sqrt{3}$ is defined in $\mathbb R$ since $3>0$ whereas the $\sqrt{-3}$ isn't defined in $\mathbb R$ because $-3\lt0$.

So to determine the domain of the *new* function $f\circ g$ we need to determine when that expression inside the square root is positive, and when it is negative. So we need to solve the following inequality: $$\begin{align}
-x^2+x+56\geqslant 0 &\overset{\text{$\times$ (-1)}}\iff x^2-x-56\leqslant0 
\end{align}$$

But how to go further? One of the ways is to use the quadratic formula to determine the roots of that polynomial, but that isn't efficient in the sense that we have $56$ there and so we will loose time computing $b^2-4ac$. A more efficient way is to find two numbers, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\alpha\cdot\beta=-56$, since when we expand $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ we get: $x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\cdot\beta$. And so, having a well defined value for $\beta$ and $\alpha$ will eventually help us factoring our polynomial.

So what are those two numbers such that their sum is $1$ and their product is $-56$. We see that their product is a negative number, so they have different signs, and their sum is a negative number, combining it from the previous remark we see that the absolute value of that negative number must be less than that of the positive number by $1$. Let's check for some divisors of $-56$:
$$\text{Divisors of }-56:\{1 , 2 , 4 , 7 , 8 , 14 , 28 , 56\,/\text{ (8 divisors)}\}$$
From this list, what are the numbers that are distanced by $1$ are $(1,2)$, $(7,8)$. Obviously, $(1,2)$ is not a solution. But let's see for the second: $7\times8=56$. And as we seen before, the *bigger* number is the positive, and the other one is negative. So the solution is: $(-7,8)$ and the polynomial factorization will be therein: $$(x-8)(x+7)$$

You can check that by expanding it. Anyway, now that we factored our polynomial, we can solve the quadratic inequality in question: $$\begin{align}
 x^2-x-56\leqslant0 &\iff (x-8)(x+7)\leqslant0 \,\,(\star)
\end{align}$$

Let's use a table to determine the solution of $(\star)$:

[image: :):):):)]
From the table, we see that $(\star)$ is equivalent to: $x\in[-7,8]$, which is the final answer!

b.t.w: $[8,-7]$ is nonsensical since $x\in[a,b]$ is defined as $a\leqslant x\leqslant b$ which means $a\leqslant b$. And so $x\in[8,-7]$ implies $8\leqslant-7$ which is totally false.